# Mathematica's Minimize function

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, puzzle

Is it true that Mathematica's `Minimize` function does not allow constraints like Mod[x,2]==0? I am trying to solve a [MinuteMath](http://amc.maa.org/mathclub/5-0,problems/M-problems/M-web,ia/2002web/m02-03-ia.shtml) puzzle with Mathematica:

> What is the smallest possible average of four distinct positive even integers?

My "solution" looks like this:

```
vars = Subscript[x, #] & /@ Range[4];
cond = Apply[And, Mod[#, 2] == 0 & /@ vars] && 
   (0 < Subscript[x, 1]) &&
   Apply[And, Table[Subscript[x, i] < Subscript[x, i + 1], {i, 1, 3}]];
Minimize[{Mean[vars], cond}, vars, Integers]
```

but `Minimize` returns unevaluated. Additional question: Can I use `EvenQ` for defining the constraints? Problem is, `EvenQ[x]` returns `False` for undefined expressions `x`.

Comment: Yes, it is very simple.. but Mathematica chokes on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A clear overkill for this problem, but useful to show some tricks.

Note that:

```
 Exists[x, Element[x, Integers] && n x == y]
```

can be used as an alternative to

```
  Mod[y,n] == 0
```

So:

```
Minimize[{(x1 + x2 + x3 + x4)/4, 0 < x1 < x2 < x3 < x4 && 
   Exists[x, Element[x, Integers] && 2 x == x1] &&
   Exists[x, Element[x, Integers] && 2 x == x2] &&
   Exists[x, Element[x, Integers] && 2 x == x3] &&
   Exists[x, Element[x, Integers] && 2 x == x4]
  },
 {x1, x2, x3, x4}, Integers]  

-> {5, {x1 -> 2, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 6, x4 -> 8}}
```

Or perhaps more elegant:

```
s = Array[x, 4];  
Minimize[{  
  Total@s,  
  Less @@ ({0} \[Union] s) &&  
   And @@ (Exists[y, Element[y, Integers] && 2 y == #] & /@ s)},
s, Integers]

--> {20, {x[1] -> 2, x[2] -> 4, x[3] -> 6, x[4] -> 8}}
```

Comment: This is really helpful, because I learn something about Mathematica. That's why I reassign the accepted answer.

Comment: @Karsten Ok. Voted up Mark's answer in retaliation :)

Comment: @Karsten I've no way to test it. Only Mma v8 here. Sorry!

Answer (score 5):

Clearly, this doens't require Mathematica but, in answer to your question, it seems that `Minimize` doesn't like the mods.  You could build it into the forumula, though, like so:

```
Minimize[{(2 x1 + 2 x2 + 2 x3 + 2 x4)/4,
  0 < x1 < x2 < x3 < x4}, {x1, x2, x3, x4}, Integers]
```

Comment: Thanks! Solving MinuteMath problems does not require Mathematica, but learning Mathematica requires easy verifiable problems, imho...

Answer (score 0):

Minimize is not good for this question, it gives a wrong solution:

`2 4 8 10`

The good solution is:

`2 4 6 12`

"Select" accept Mod function it's better than Minimize
Minimize gives the wrong solution.

Play this programe and see:

```
Res=Select[Permutations[Range@20 {4}],Mod[ #[[1]],2]==0 &&Mod[ #[[2]],2]==0&&Mod[#[[3]],2]==0 &&Mod[#[[4]],2]==0&&Mod[(#[[1]]+#[[2]]+#[[3]]+#[[4]])/4,2]==0 &];Sort[Res,Less];Res[[1]]
```